# How to open a pop dialog on click of hyperlink in a gridview (another popup)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, popup, modal-dialog

I have a hyper link which will open a grid view popup, which have name and other details, and the name is a hyperlink in it.When I click on that hyperlink i need to display the details of that user in another popup. How can i do it?

My Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdNomiantionCountDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                    PagerStyle-CssClass="dvPageNation1" PagerSettings-Position="Bottom" GridLines="None"
                                    PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="true" Width="600px" HorizontalAlign="center">
 <Columns>                                             

  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nominated By" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemStyle CssClass="bdrstyle" />
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <br />                                                   
                                                <asp:HyperLink Width="180px" CssClass="txtcolor" runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" Text='<%#Bind("NominatorName")%>' onclick='<%# String.Format("return viewDescription(""{0}"");",Eval("Description")) %>'></asp:HyperLink>                                                   
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="hdrstyle" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Institution" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hdrstyle">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="400px" CssClass="txtcolor bdrstyle " />
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <br />                                                
                                                    <asp:Label Width="180px" CssClass="txtcolor" runat="server" ID="lblInstitution" Text='<%#Bind("Institution")%>' />
                                                <br />        
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <PagerStyle CssClass="dvPageNation1" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </div>
```

And i need to open a dialog with the description, on click of the  NominatorName hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<asp:HyperLink Width="180px" CssClass="txtcolor" runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" Text='<%#Bind("NominatorName")%>' onclick='<%# String.Format("return viewDescription(""{0}"");",Eval("Description")) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

with something like

```
<div onclick="openPopupDialog('<%# Eval("Description") %>')">ClickMe</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i need to bind the gridview data from DB..the gridview may contain names of different users.

Comment: What does your piece of code do then? Is that what should be inside the popup?